# EF Core 6 EntityTypeBuilder.HasData() doesn't create seed data in migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm fiddling around with a small EF Core 6 practice project, and I'm having some minor problems getting my seed data working properly.

This is some of my code:

### `CourseEntity`

```
public class CourseEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CourseLevel Level { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; } = null;
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; } = null;
    
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }
    public InstructorEntity Instructor { get; set; }
}
```

### `BaseEntity`

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

### `CourseEntityConfiguration`

```
public class CourseEntityConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<CourseEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CourseEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Course");

        builder.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(c => c.Level).IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne(c => c.Instructor)
            .WithMany(i => i.Courses)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.InstructorId);

        builder.HasData(new List<CourseEntity>
        {
            new()
            {
                Id = 1,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                Name = "Mathematics Nov.",
                Description = "Mathematics for beginners.",
                Level = CourseLevel.Novice,
                StartDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 1),
                EndDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 31),
                InstructorId = 1
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### `BaseEntityConfiguration`

```
public class BaseEntityConfiguration<TBase> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TBase> where TBase : BaseEntity
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TBase> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);

        builder.Property(b => b.CreatedDate)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(b => b.UpdatedDate)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

### `Context`

```
public class PlaygroundDbContext : DbContext
{
    public PlaygroundDbContext(DbContextOptions<PlaygroundDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<CourseEntity> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InstructorEntity> Instructors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that in `CourseEntityConfiguration`, `EntityTypeBuilder.HasData()` doesn't create the configured seed data in the later on generated migration file. All other configuration is applied and the database is being created successfully - but no seed data.

If I configure the seed data in my context instead like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    modelBuilder.Entity<CourseEntity>().HasData(new List<CourseEntity>
        {
            new()
            {
                Id = 1,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                Name = "Mathematics Nov.",
                Description = "Mathematics for beginners.",
                Level = CourseLevel.Novice,
                StartDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 1),
                EndDate = new DateTime(2022, 8, 31),
                InstructorId = 1
            }
        });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

then it works as it should, and seed data gets created in the generated migration file.

I'd rather not have all my seed data configuration in my context though. I remember working with something similar on an earlier project, but I can't get a hold on that source code anymore, as it is locked behind customers gates now.

I have been Googling for a couple of days now, but can't find any solution to it. I found [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1588) on GitHub describing the exact same problem. But where they are using PostgreSQL, I am using SQL Server. And the issue is closed with no solution.

## Edit

On request from @Ivan Stoev, I have added my BaseEntity and BaseEntityConfiguration classes.

If anybody could help me get towards a solution, I would be very grateful.

Comment: `HasData()` is only recommended for static data and your `CourseEntity` has a limited lifetime that suggests it might be better suited to a [Custom initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#custom-initialization-logic) instead. Take note of the warnings on that page, including that due to concurrency issues seeding should not be part of normal application code - the inference being that you need a seperate boot-strapper process that handles your migrations.

Comment: Most likely the `Configure` method of `CourseEntityConfiguration` is not called. Since you are not implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` directly, it will be good to show the `BaseEntityConfiguration<T>` class.

Comment: As it is currently, you have two public methods with one and the same signature (you should be getting compiler warning btw), and I think the interface is implemented  by the method in the base class, so that method is called by EF Core, and you method in the derived class is simiply not called. In order to fix it, `public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TBase> builder)` in the base class must be `virtual`. Then in the `CourseEntityConfiguration` class you need to **override** it, calls the base implementation and then the specific code.

Comment: Ofcourse @IvanStoev!! `Virtual` and `Override` did the trick. How did I not see this?. What I also didn't notice was that the `Configure()` method in the `CourseEntityConfiguration` class was greyed out with the message "Method 'Configure' is never used". Thank you very much for your help. Please add your answer, and I will Accept it.